# Clipping of sound files + Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is it somehow possible to clip a sound file i between ? In my application I have to provide the user the ability to create a ringtone out of a sound file and the user will enter the start and end time of the region within the file he wants to clip .Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Parse mp3 (or other sound) binary format and do whatever you want with this file. Information on mp3 and other file formats can be found via google.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have read somewhere that all sound files contains a header(which tells whether a file is of 3gp or mp3 or any other format) at the beginning of file. Clipping a sound file in between might remove that header as well leaving the clipped sound unplayable.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Clipping is not about just removing a part of binary file. Clipping is more complicated than appears. You will need to compose a new header with new byte sequence that represents a part of the processed big sound file.